# Tikz obtain node coordinates

Tags: nodes, circuitikz, coordinates

In tikzpicture, how do I get a single coordinate of a node?

[image]

This is the circuit I'm making, and I need to know the x coordinate of the node (opamp.out) so that i can make R2 vertically aligned with that node, and link it with a vertical line.
This is my code for R2:

> \draw (opamp.-) to [short,*-] ++(0,1) node{} to [R,l=$R_2$]
>   ++(2,0);

where, instead of ++(2,0), I would like to input ++(opamp.out.x-opamp.-.x,0);

Comment: `\draw let \p1=(opamp.out),\p2=(opamp.-) in (opamp.-) to [short,*-] ++(0,1) node{} to [R,l=$R_2$] ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);`
Note that you have to `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`

Comment: Glad it worked. I've not tested it XD. I'll turn into an answer.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

## An alternative: use of orthogonal coordinate

`(p -| q)` refers to the point horizontally aligned with `p` and vertically aligned with `q`. The `-|` was chosen in such a way that it's easy to remember which is which; the `-` side is horizontal, and the `|` side is vertical. The [CircuiTikz manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#page=21) has further information.

### Complete Examples:

[image: Resulting Diagram]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}

An alternative solution

\begin{circuitikz}  
\draw
(0,0) node[op amp](opamp){}
(opamp.out) to[short,*-o] (2,0)node[]{} node[right]{$v_{out}$};
\draw (opamp.-) -- ++(-0.2,0) to[R,l_=$R_1$] ++ (-2,0)node[ground,rotate=-90]{};
\draw (opamp.+) to[short,-o] ++ (-0.5,0)node[left]{$V_{in}$};

\draw (opamp.-) to [short,*-] ++(0,1) node{} to [R,l=$R_2$] ([yshift=1cm]opamp.- -|opamp.out);
\end{circuitikz}

\medskip

@Astrinus' solution

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) node[op amp](opamp){}
(opamp.out) to[short,*-o] (2,0)node[]{} node[right]{$v_{out}$};

\draw (opamp.-) -- ++(-0.2,0) to[R,l_=$R_1$] ++ (-2,0)node[ground,rotate=-90]{};
\draw (opamp.+) to[short,-o] ++ (-0.5,0)node[left]{$V_{in}$};

\draw let \p1=(opamp.out),\p2=(opamp.-) in (opamp.-) to [short,*-] ++(0,1) 
node{} to [R,l=$R_2$] ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\draw let \p1=(opamp.out),\p2=(opamp.-) in (opamp.-) to [short,*-] ++(0,1) node{} to [R,l=$R_2$] ++($(\x1,0)-(\x2,0)$);`

Note that you have to `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`.

The `let` syntax let you alias the points with names `\p1 ... \pN`, where `N` is the number of points. Then, after `in`, you could access points' coordinates with the syntax `\x1 .. \xN` and `\y1 .. \yN` (I think it's possible to access also polar coordinates but honestly I don't remember the syntax :-8), matching the order of `\p` assignments.

The library `calc` let you make calculations with coordinates and get the resulting coordinates, with the syntax `($<calculations>$)`.

Look at `pgfmanual.pdf` or at "TikZ pour l'impatient" if you read french (I can't speak french at all, but since my mother language is neo latin I had absolutely no problem reading it).